# Dependency injection through method with Resharper or DevExpress

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, refactoring, devexpress, resharper-6.0

I want to inject a dependency in one of my class and I don't know if there is a refactor in tools like `Resharper` or `DevExpress` to do that.

Here is my class:

```
   public class ClassWithInjections
   {
      private Dependency _fieldInjected;
   }

   public class Dependency
   {

   }
```

And the final result I want it to look like: (Note that the field can now be initialized by the method `Initialize`)

```
   public class ClassWithInjections
   {
      private Dependency _fieldInjected;

      public void Initialize(Dependency fieldInjected)
      {
         _fieldInjected = fieldInjected;
      }
   }
```

I want to be able to just activate a refactor option while specifying my field with the mouse cursor and then the tool that could suggest me if I want to inject the dependency with method, property or constructor.

With `Resharper`, you can do that with 'Encapsulate field' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or creating a constructor with the code generation tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd>) but I don't found any option to inject my dependency with the 'method' technique.

Anybody have the solution?

Comment: @AustinSalonen This is exactly what I said at the end of my question but it's not the type of injection that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DevExpress Refactor! Pro > Create Setter Method](http://help.devexpress.com/#RefactorPro/CustomDocument1716) refactoring option for this purpose.

Comment: Arggggggg!!! Each time I want to 'reinstall' DevExpress when I always have Resharper, Visual Studio look like a fat pig being slower and slower. I think I will just keep Resharper and do the refactor manually. Thank you Mikhail.

Answer (score 4):

First of all. You should not inject dependencies using methods. [Read here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling.aspx). I would only use property injection to solve the circular dependencies problem.

That leaves constructor injection.

Resharper can help you. Press `ALT+ENTER` on the field and choose "Initialize in constructor"

> I don't found any option to inject my dependency with the 'method' technique.

Well. It doesn't exist since you should avoid that ;)

Comment: Like I said in my question, I know how to inject from constructor with recharger and I understand the pros and cons of injection with the help of method. I known method injection can create temporal coupling in the concept of encapsulation but I want to do that anyways in my case.